# Nginx Redirect Rule with a anchor tag

Tags: nginx, web-server, redirect

I have an existing redirect rule

```
location ~* "^/view-price-range.php" {
    return 301 $scheme://www.mysite.com.au/pricing/;
}
```

Is it possible for nginx to detect anchor tag and have a redirect rule?

For example  `view-price-range.php#mytag`

What I want is if that url is being requested it will go to `/pricing/` as well.

So tried:

```
location ~* "^/view-price-range.php#mytag" {
    return 301 $scheme://www.mysite.au/pricing/;
}
```

And not working. I am not sure if the `#` in the url is being evaluated as comment in nginx?

Comment: What does exactly "not working" mean here? Please post `curl` output for both scenarios.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

nginx never receives the part after `#` in the HTTP request, it is purely a HTTP client (browser) side concept.

This means that the following regexp will match both `/view-price-range.php` and `/view-price-range.php#mytag`:

```
location ~ ^/view-price-range.php$ {
    ...
}
```